# Атрибут формы Pattern работает некорректно

Tags: html, css

Есть инпут с паттерном

```html
<form class="win-cen l2" method="POST" style="position:relative; max-width: 100%">
                <input class="minecraft-inp loginer" type="text" name="register_name" placeholder="Имя пользователя" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]" minlength="4" maxlength="16" onclick="this.classList.remove('col-c')">
                <input class="minecraft-btn" type="submit">
            </form>
```

На отсутствие стиля забейте :), суть в том что с данным паттерном и ограничениями длины в поле должны быть русские и английские буквы в количестве от 4 до 16, но почему то браузер не дает отправлять форму от слова совсем.

Comment: ради примера даже 'admin' не работает :(

Comment: ḁ̷̢̧̛̞̲̰̥̦͎̬̻̃̍̑̔̓̀̀́́̓̆̚̕͜͠͠x̵̪͔̲̻̫̼͙͔͕̞̠̣̅̈̈́͛̈̇̓̉̑̐̌͋̽́̀̈̿́̚͘͜͠͠ḁ̵̡̧̣͉̃̇͗̽̓̒̀̀̈́̈̈́̈̚x̸̨̺̲͔͚̆̈́͑͊̇̋̓̔̆̚ḁ̴̡̡̡̨̛̛̛̠̘͈̠͖̣͈̟̦̞̦̹̮̟͍͔̩͉͕̞̯̙̠͕͔̟̠̣̯̔̾̑̈́̄͋͌̑̒͛̀̾̌̂̈́̀̊̆̔̉̕̚͜͜͝͝͠͠ͅx̵̧̨̛̫̘͍̳̝̲̭̬̰̋̓͛̌͊̈̉́̽̃̑̀͒̓̽͑͊̾̓̈̕͠͝͝a̷͍̙͈̪͕̭̞̮̤̤͍̮̬̩͈͙͔̤̚͜͜ͅͅẍ̷̧̢̢̧̡̛̗̥̩̜̼̩̲̗̼͙̮̩̮͎̬̞̫̺͚͎͔͓̳͚̖̱̞́̊͑̂̀̆̒͛̍̓͌̄́̏̒̀͊̈́̓͂̈́͐̍̌̾̄̏͘̕̕͘̕̕ͅã̴̢̧͓͎͕̖͙̲̜̩͖̤̭̞̩̮̠̍̎̽̽̅̏̚x̸̡̡͍̜͚̦̗͎̞̜̜͙͖̘̰̻̪̰̝̹͖͉̭̰͇̺̰̟͉͍̤̙̏̏͘͜ǎ̶̢̧̧̛̦̲͈̝̜̩͍̝͍̣̱͔̗̘̗̘̞̤͓̤̩́͂͆̋̇͗̈́̽̀̑͋̿͗͗̾̒̚̚̚̚

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашей регулярке получается, что введенные данные должны содержать всего один символ, поэтому и не пропускает. Добавьте в паттерн `*` или размерность в формате {*от*, *до*}, и все будет работать

```html
<form class="win-cen l2" method="POST" style="position:relative; max-width: 100%">
                <input class="minecraft-inp loginer" type="text" name="register_name" placeholder="Имя пользователя" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]*" minlength="4" maxlength="16" onclick="this.classList.remove('col-c')">
                <input class="minecraft-btn" type="submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: спасибо большое